# bpy.context.active_object not getting set when using bpy as python module inside a script

Tags: python

I'm using Blender as Python module and facing an issue.

I have a consumer based workflow in which I'm using bpy.

```
### consumer.py

from scripts.file1 import method1
method1(filepath)


#### file1.py
import bpy
frome export import export_scene
def method1(filepath):
     bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
     bpy.ops.object.delete()
     import_model(filepath)
     ### some more operations
    export_scene(new_file_path)
`

#### export.py
import bpy
def export_scene(filepath):

     bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(filepath)
```

but getting following errror:

```
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'active_object'
Location: /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bpy/3.6/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:113
```